# Create a dictionary on Language Tool

Tags: java, dictionary, languagetool

I'm trying to create a french dictionary to use it on Language Tool Spelling checker.
The code itself seems to create it, but it's not my case because I can't find the .dict file on my folder.
Hope you can help me - maybe it's just an erroneous use of Java code.

```
java -cp languagetool.jar org.languagetool.tools.SpellDictionaryBuilder fr_FR -i C:/Users/KP/Desktop/LanguageTool/french_dict.txt -info org/languagetool/resource/fr/french.info -o C:/Users/KP/Desktop/LanguageTool/output.dict

    Running Morfologik FSACompile.main with these options: [--exit, false, -i, C:\Users\KP\AppData\Local\Temp\SpellDictionaryBuilder257816875475185246.txt, -o, C:\Users\KP\Desktop\LanguageTool\output.dict, -f, CFSA2, --overwrite]
    Invalid argument: Unknown option: --overwrite

    Usage: fsa_compile [options]
    Options:
            --accept-bom
               Accept leading BOM bytes (UTF-8).
               Default: false
            --accept-cr
               Accept CR bytes in input sequences (\r).
               Default: false
            -f, --format
               Automaton serialization format.
               Default: FSA5
               Possible Values: [FSA5, CFSA2]
            --ignore-empty
               Ignore empty lines in the input.
               Default: false
          * -i, --input
               The input sequences (one sequence per \n-delimited line).
          * -o, --output
               The output automaton file.
    Done. The binary dictionary has been written to C:\Users\KP\Desktop\LanguageTool\output.dict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in LanguageTool that has been fixed in the nightly builds: http://forum.languagetool.org/t/create-a-dictionary-for-french-language/852/21?u=dnaber